# what's wrong if I have an input as list?

Tags: python

I have the following works fine when I have a string input, but it throws an error of `" TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"`, when the input is a list of int, plz advice:

```
def permutation(string):
    result=[]
    if len(string)== 0:
        return [[]]
    if len(string)==1:
        return [string]

    perms= permutation(string[1:])

    print("perms are", perms)
    char= string[0]
    for i in range(len(string)+1):
        for perm in perms:
            result.append(perm[i:]+char+perm[:i])

    return result

print(permutation([1,2,3])
```

And why this code works fine?

```
def permute(nums):
    return [[n] + p
            for i, n in enumerate(nums)
            for p in permute(nums[:i] + nums[i+1:])] or [[]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
result.append(perm[i:]+char+perm[:i])
```

won't work when `char` is an int, since `+` can append lists, but not an int and a list.  Python doesn't have a separate character type, so in the string case, char is just a one-element string, so string concatenation works with `+`.

In the int case, you could do:

```
result.append(perm[i:]+[char]+perm[:i])
```

which wraps `char` in a list, which can now be concatenated.